# Google Chrome with buggy launcher

Tags: google-chrome, docky

Google Chrome used to work for me, but today it started to act weirdly. When I open it(on Docky), it will create a new window instead of keeping on its own icon. To fix that, I ran `sudo apt-get purge google-chrome stable` and then re-installed it. But now it is worse. Before, the new window had a title and a blurry icon, now it has no title and no icon.
Is there a way to fix it? what should be done?

Comment: I am pretty sure the fact that you use Docky is not relevant. The cause is the same. Especially with Chrome, these things happen frequently.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think my question is a duplicate. The solution in the other question just made everything worse. I now don't have any  desktop icon.

Comment: You shouldn't have removed them all ;). I think the most convenient thing to do (after you removed *all* the desktop files in both `~/.local/share/applications` and `/usr/share/applications`), is to simply uninstall / reinstall. Hardly possible that you will have problems after that.

Comment: I removed only one file, the one in .local. But, I solved my issue. After I removed the desktop file, I found another in the internet and added it to my .local folder, now it works. My desktop file was probably wrong, even though I didn't touch it after I installed Chrome.